# Spring Rabbit CachingConnectionFactory Thread Pool

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

[image]I have around 10 different rabbit mq queues in 10 different virtual hosts to connect to. For each queue, a separate SimpleMessageListenerContainer bean is defined in my spring boot application and a separate Spring Integration flow is created using each specific SimpleMessageListenerContainer.

The concurrency for SimpleMessageListenerContainer is set to 1-3. Each of the SimpleMessageListenerContainer bean is using separate CachingConnectoryFacory beans. The Connection Factory mode is set as CHANNEL.

We also have another IntegrationFlow to publish messages to an outbound queue that is using a different connection factory. I am not setting any ThreadPool Task Executors in the ConnectionFactory, so it using the default one. While doing the Load test we are noticing that the multiple thread pool (prefixed with pool-) are getting crated and after a certain point application crashes may due to the high number of threads.

It looks like the default thread pool executor is having max value of Integer unbounded which may spinning up threads based on the demand. I tried setting custom Thread Pool task executors for each connection factory and I noticed that the threads are not growing like previously but from the java profiler it shows the SimpleMessageListenerContainer threads are getting BLOCKED frequently.

I want to know if there any best practices or to be followed while setting the custom thread pool task executors in the connection factory like a ratio between Lisneter threads and connection factory threads etc?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. With no executor, the amqp-client (in each CF) creates a fixed pool executor with `private static final int DEFAULT_NUM_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;`. The number of threads in the connection factory has no bearing on the listener container threads. It is not clear what you mean by blocked in this context; if you are using a single fixed pool across all the factories you may need more threads. If you can provide a minimal, complete, reproducible example that exhibits this behavior, we can take a look to see what's wrong.

Comment: I agree with the DEFAULT_NUM_THREADS, but the maximum limit is Integer.MAX_VALUE  with no executor which means depending on the load, the threads can go unbounded. As a best practice, do you recommend setting custom thread pools with  max limit  for each connection factory?

Comment: Please explain where you see an unbounded executor; as I said, it has a fixed pool.

Comment: Ok..I understand... plese refer to the image attched. My machine is 2 core and 4 logical processors. Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2 returns 8 in my machine, but the images shows thread pool with 9 threads. eg: pool-12 .. also the thread-1 is missing from all the thread-ppol ? Can you please advice what is happening?

Comment: No idea - must be some quirk of the pooled executor ; I have 16 logical CPUs and I end up with 17 threads (`...-2` through `...-18`). I have no idea what happens to `...-1`.

Comment: I have done some debugging; `...-1` gets renamed to, for example `AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672`. That thread is not from the pool, but it is created by the same thread factory. Similarly, the scheduled executor (for heartbeats) uses the same thread factory, and gets `...-2`. Hence the pool starts at `...-3`. So indeed, you have a fixed pool of 8 threads, an I/O thread, and a heartbeat thread for each factory.

Comment: With a large number of factories like that, you probably don't need so many threads; I would suggest a single pooled executor with sufficient threads to satisfy your workload; experimentation is probably the only way to determine the number, but I would guess it's something less than 88 (11x8).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The explanation is very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some debugging; `...-1` gets renamed to, for example `AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672`.

That thread is not from the pool, but it is created by the same thread factory.

Similarly, the scheduled executor (for heartbeats) uses the same thread factory, and gets `...-2`.

Hence the pool starts at `...-3`. So indeed, you have a fixed pool of 8 threads, an I/O thread, and a heartbeat thread for each factory.

With a large number of factories like that, you probably don't need so many threads; I would suggest a single pooled executor with sufficient threads to satisfy your workload; experimentation is probably the only way to determine the number, but I would guess it's something less than 88 (11x8).